# Why is $\exp(i \pi / 2^\ell Y)$ in the $\ell$ level of the Clifford Hiearrchy?

Tags: clifford-group, clifford-hierarchy

I'm confused about the definition of the Clifford hierarchy and would like resources to learn more. For example, in https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.04230, they define the hierarchy as:
[image: Campbell and O'Gorman's definition of the hierarchy]
However, in prior stack exchange posts, it is defined as follows:
[image: Stack exchange definition]
Where membership has been interchanged. Which is correct, and how does it relate to the claim that $R_\ell = \exp (i \pi / 2^\ell Y) \in \mathcal{C}^\ell$? What resources are useful to learn more?